# `.jsconfig` but for php paths in vscode

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I have a laravel project and frequently uses Facade with a usage of something like

```
\MyCustomFacade::renewalDate()
```

which point to a class `/src/Classes/MyCustomFacade@renewalDate`.

The goal is that VScode definition of the facade usage will point to the correct file class path.

Answer (score 0):

try this [package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

its index all your facade model controller routes view you create and auto import your class by typing your facade